# Promise error because of bad format

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I created a new RestAdapter like so.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',
  host: 'http://localhost:8081'
});
```

if i look at the network calls the api gets called properly and returns this data.

```
{
      "environments": [
        {
          "Id": 1,
          "LocalePath": "C:\\XML_DEPOT",
          "Name": "Acceptation 1",
          "RemotePath": "D:\\XML_DEPOT",
          "DatabaseServerName": "somedata",
          "DatabaseName": "somedata",
          "Port": 60903
        },
        {
          "Id": 2,
          "LocalePath": "bob",
          "Name": "Acceptation 2",
          "RemotePath": "bob",
          "DatabaseServerName": "somedata\\somedata",
          "DatabaseName": "somedata",
          "Port": 60904
        }
    ]
}
```

and then i get an error saying that

> Assertion Failed: normalizeResponse must return a valid JSON API
>   document

but from what i understand the adapter is not a JSONAPIAdapter so it shouldnt try to serialize it has a jsonapi ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Data is using JSON Api spec internally since version 1.13 as [described in release notes](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html). [`normalizeResponse`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizeResponse) method of DS.RestAdapter "is used to normalize a payload from the server to a JSON-API Document."

Your payload does not look like what ember data RestAdapater excepts as default. RestAdapter expects camelCase keys but yours are CamelCase. You have to customize your serializer [`keyForAttribute`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.5.2/addon/serializers/rest.js#L35-L48) method to get it working.

Comment: leads to another problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36772796/empty-content-from-promise