# Empty content from promise?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using **ember-data**, I call to my API using

```
this.store.findAll('environment').then(function(values){
  //1
},function(reason){
  //rejected
});
```

And my code does go into the //1, problem is I get this object which seems pretty invalid.

[image]

---

Here is what my api sends back.

```
{
  "data": {
    "environments": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "localePath": "C:\\XML_DEPOT",
        "name": "Acceptation 1",
        "remotePath": "D:\\XML_DEPOT",
        "databaseServerName": "blabla",
        "databaseName": "blabla",
        "port": 60903
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "localePath": "bob",
        "name": "Acceptation 2",
        "remotePath": "bob",
        "databaseServerName": "blabla\\blabla",
        "databaseName": "blabla",
        "port": 60904
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

on the second try i gave it this and still didnt like it.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "localePath": "C:\\XML_DEPOT",
      "name": "Acceptation 1",
      "remotePath": "D:\\XML_DEPOT",
      "databaseServerName": "W050A01SQL1",
      "databaseName": "MAMROT01P1_MSCRM",
      "port": 60903,
      "type": "environments"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "localePath": "bob",
      "name": "Acceptation 2",
      "remotePath": "bob",
      "databaseServerName": "W050A01SQL1\\W050A01SQL1B02",
      "databaseName": "MAMROT01P1_MSCRM",
      "port": 60904,
      "type": "environments"
    }
  ]
}
```

this is my model declaration

```
//environment.js
export default Model.extend({
  id: DS.attr('number'),
  localePath: DS.attr('string'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  remotePath: DS.attr('string'),
  databaseServerName: DS.attr('string'),
  databaseName: DS.attr('string'),
  port: DS.attr('number')
});
```

Thank you !

Comment: Answer: change "data" to "environments" and remove id in the model

Comment: Yeah, "id" is assumed. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Ember you are using, and assuming your **environments** model is set up well (maybe you could list that just so we can rule that out), you would want the server to send you back data in one of two formats to make Ember Data happy:

1. Ember 1.13 (or earlier version) with its default `DS.RESTAdapter` ([docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_json-conventions))

   ```
   {
     "environments": [
       {
         "id": 1,
         "localePath": "C:\\XML_DEPOT",
         "name": "Acceptation 1",
         "remotePath": "D:\\XML_DEPOT",
         "databaseServerName": "blabla",
         "databaseName": "blabla",
         "port": 60903
       },
       {
         "id": 2,
         "localePath": "bob",
         "name": "Acceptation 2",
         "remotePath": "bob",
         "databaseServerName": "blabla\\blabla",
         "databaseName": "blabla",
         "port": 60904
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Ember 2.0+ with its default `DS.JSONAPIAdapter` ([docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_json-api-document))

   ```
   {
     "data": [
       {
         "type": "environments",
         "id": 1,
         "attributes": {
           "localePath": "C:\\XML_DEPOT",
           "name": "Acceptation 1",
           "remotePath": "D:\\XML_DEPOT",
           "databaseServerName": "blabla",
           "databaseName": "blabla",
           "port": 60903
         }
       },
       {
         "type": "environments",
         "id": 2,
         "attributes": {
           "localePath": "bob",
           "name": "Acceptation 2",
           "remotePath": "bob",
           "databaseServerName": "blabla\\blabla",
           "databaseName": "blabla",
           "port": 60904
         }
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

And your model can drop the ID attribute, as you've discovered since it's assumed and added for you by Ember.

```
//environment.js
export default Model.extend({
  localePath: DS.attr('string'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  remotePath: DS.attr('string'),
  databaseServerName: DS.attr('string'),
  databaseName: DS.attr('string'),
  port: DS.attr('number')
});
```

Hope that gets you what you're after.

Comment: I dont get it from this doc  http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html

if i use the RESTAdapter which i do the way i send my json should be fine ? This doesnt seem from an old doc version.

Comment: @Dr.DenisMcCracleJizz I think you still need to drop the `"data": {}` wrapper when using the RESTAdapter. It looks like it's still looking for the Ember 1.13 style JSON. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Also, you should be able to remove the `"data": ()` wrapper with a `normalize` hook/method if you can't get the server to behave. http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalize

Comment: well almost, it needed "environments" and not data

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was saying, :c) like in my **Ember 1.13** example above right. What I meant be removing the `"data": {}` part was removing it from your **first try** where you have `"data": {"environments": [{},{}] }` . I'm always glad to here when somebody figures out how to match all the conventions and get Ember Data to play nice!

Comment: your 2.0 exemple says "data" : {} but it should be "environment" : {}

Comment: also am having alot of problem finding how to use the data that i received. I dont have any errors so i guess they're fine. Its just the this.store.findAll('environment') gives me something that seems to be hard to work with. Prolly an error there too.

Comment: @EricD.Johnson Second example is not a valid JSON API document. Also it does not depend on ember version being used but on Adapter. `RESTAdapter` is part of for Ember Data 2.x as well even so it's not the default one. On the other hand `JSONAPIAdapter` is part of Ember Data since 1.13.x.

Comment: @jelhan, I'm totally with you that with `RESTAdapter` the Ember Data Version doesn't matter. @Dr.Denis McCracleJizz never told me he was not using the `JSONAPIAdapter` when I first answered him. I'll update my answer to help clarify.

Comment: @Dr.DenisMcCracleJizz, I'm pretty sure my answer does now answer the question originally asked. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @jelhan  I'm pretty sure my answer does now answer the question originally asked. Thanks for the feedback on the http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-objects hint.